# Cannot get apache mod_perl with mpirun to work

Tags: apache, web-services, perl, mpi, mod-perl

I am trying to build a simple web service that runs on an ubuntu machine with apache and mod_perl2. The service runs `mpirun` and returns the output of the call.
I invoke a call of the apache response handler via the web browser. The problem is that the `mpirun` command seems to hang.

**Important:**
This problem occurs on a server running Ubuntu (12.04.4) with apache, mod_perl and openmpi. When running it on my mac (Macos 10.9.3), it works fine and mpirun returns. On both machines, openmpi is installed in the same version (1.6.5)

Here my mod_perl handler:

```
package MyHandler;
use Apache2::Const '-compile' => 'OK';

sub handler {
        my $command = "mpirun -np 4 echo test";
        my $out = qx($command);
        print $out;
        return Apache2::Const::OK;
}
1;
```

The mpirun job does not seem to finish. A `ps aux | grep mpirun` gives me this:

```
www-data 24023  0.0  0.1  23600  2424 ?        S    13:02   0:00 mpirun -np 4 echo test
```

When I do a `kilall -9 mpirun`, the service comes back with the result.

No errors are written to the apache error log.

Here is what I tried/tested:

- made sure that the command `mpirun -np 4 echo test` generates the correct output when run as user `www-data`
- tried to invoke `mpirun` in different ways: Using `IPC::Run` and `IPC::Run3`, as suggested by Sergei, I also tried using pipes, but everytime mpirun dies not finish.
- tried to call the handler directly via a perl script and not via the browser: mpirun finishes and the handler prints the desired output.
- compared  the outputs of `ompi_info --param mpi all` on both machines, mac and ubuntu, but found no differences

Any idea why mpirun would hang in my situation or any idea how I could debug this?

**Edit**

I tried to use [Apache2::SubProcess](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/SubProcess.html) as suggested by hrunting. Here my code following the simple example from the link:

```
package MyHandler;
use Apache2::SubProcess ();
use Apache2::Const '-compile' => 'OK';
use Apache2::Request;
use Config;
use constant PERLIO_IS_ENABLED => $Config{useperlio};

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    my $command = "mpirun -np 4 echo test";
    my ($in_fh, $out_fh, $err_fh) = $r->spawn_proc_prog($command);
    $r->content_type('text/plain');
    my $output = read_data($out_fh);
    my $error  = read_data($err_fh);
    print "output : $output \n";
    print "error : $error \n";
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

# helper function to work w/ and w/o perlio-enabled Perl                                                                                                                                                  
sub read_data {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my $data;
    if (PERLIO_IS_ENABLED || IO::Select->new($fh)->can_read(10)) {
        $data = <$fh>;
    }
    return defined $data ? $data : '';

}
1;
```

This does not work for me. When calling the handler from the browser, I get the output:

```
output :  
error :
```

and `ps aux` tells me that mpirun is not running.

Any further ideas of how I could debug this and get `mpirun` to work with my configuration?

Comment: Problem solved: When installing apache and mod_perl on Ubuntu 12.04 via apt-get, the installed apache 2.2.22 does not seem to handle such system calls with mod_perl. Installing mod_perl 2.08 and and apache 2.2.27 solved the problem!

Comment: You should write that as an answer so future visitors with the same issue can see what fixed the problem.

Comment: good idea, because I found that the problem is reproducible with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04: I tested it again with a fresh Virtualbox machine, installed mpi, mod_perl and apache with `apt-get` -- mpirun does not work with apache.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Apache2::SubProcess`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/SubProcess.html). When you're running external processes within a mod_perl handler, Apache memory, I/O and process management come into play. Remember, your code is running within Apache itself and is subject to the Apache environment. The `Apache2::SubProcess` module is designed to make `exec()`- and `system()`-style calls work properly under within Apache.

Note that the module documentation outlines caveats for dealing with different Perl configurations.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Apache2::SubProcess, but it seems as it does not work for me. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try IPC::Run or IPC::Run3 to run your command.

Answer (score 0):

[`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) works for me. I'm not sure it'll work well under `mod_perl` (it may interact badly with the file handles for the request and response) but it works fine as a regular script:

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ( $stdout, $stderr, $exit ) = capture {
    system( qw(mpirun -np 4 echo test) );
};

print "stdout: $stdout\n";
print "stderr: $stderr\n";
print "exit: $exit\n";
```

Prints:

```
stdout: test
test
test
test

stderr:
exit: 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found that `Capture::Tiny` works in general for my system calls, however, on my ubuntu server, it still does not work, started MPI processes just don't finish...